# How to parse nested Json Object inside Array Data in Ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, http-post

i have JSON data into below format , how can i post values into it because it gives me error: Domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain" Json Text did not start with array or object and options to allow fragments not set !!!  please help!!!

```
[
 { "No:"1" , "firstname":dhruv ....},
 { "No:"2", "firstname" : something i want to post...} ]
```

code:

```
Nsstring* URL string = [NStringwithformat:@Myurl?fname=%(value from editext ]
```

Comment: can you show the full error

Comment: and can you show ur tried code

Comment: What is the format of your data and how are you adding it?

Comment: Have you searched? There are hundreds of related questions and answers. There are even a few in the *Related* column.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthikr I UPDATE MY CODE !!!!

Comment: @TusharSharma i give the example of above json format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray *arrData = @[@{
                          @"No": @"1",
                          @"firstname": @"dhruv"},
                        @{
                           @"No": @"2",
                           @"firstname": @"something i want to post"
                        }];

NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arrData options:0 error:nil];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your url here"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
NSURLSessionUploadTask *dataTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest: request
                                                             fromData:data completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                                 //Kindly use below either one  according to your response
                                                                 //If the response is in Dictionary format
                                                                 NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
                                                                 NSLog(@"%@", jsonDict);

                                                                 //If the response is in Array format
                                                                 NSArray *jsonArr = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
                                                                 NSLog(@"%@", jsonArr);
                                                             }];

[dataTask resume];
```